# Curry compiler zinc cannot be configured

Tags: haskell, curry

when I configure curry's compiler zinc, I get this:

```
checking for Haskell 98 compiler... 
checking for ghc... ghc
checking ghc version... 7.0
checking whether ghc supports Haskell 98... [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( conftest.hs, conftest.o )
yes
using ghc for compilation
checking how to import IOExts... configure: error: import of IOExts does not work
```

so what's IOExts? where can I find it?

Comment: I find mcc also offer a version which support type class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pushing up daisies is what it is. An old library module that existed about five years ago--you can find some information [in the documentation for older GHC releases](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.4-latest/html/hslibs/sec-IOExts.html). I'm guessing that the code you're trying to compile is of a similar age.

Assuming there isn't an updated version of zinc somewhere, your choices are roughly:

- Use an antique version of GHC to build it.
- Update the code yourself to import whatever modules the contents of `IOExts` ended up in.
- Create a mock-IOExts module that reexports the necessary stuff.

Assuming there aren't other problems, the third is probably easiest as a quick hack. There's a fair chance you'll run into more compatibility issues than just this one, though, so grabbing a copy of GHC 6.4 might be the simplest thing overall, particularly if you're not sufficiently comfortable mucking about with the source code.

Comment: So is Curry pushing up daisies?

Comment: @amindfv: I wouldn't know. But I'm pretty sure there are other implementations of it, so this one being unmaintained for the last five years doesn't mean that much.